# TypeScript type cast & D3.js errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, d3.js

Now, how should I solve this/typecast this?

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { arc, pie, DSVRowArray, csv, PieArcDatum } from "d3";

const CSVURL =
  "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mzs21/df0621d1ca5a25fa6baeeae93562c1a1/raw/CSSNamedColors.csv";

const width = 960;
const height = 500;
const centerX = width / 2;
const centerY = height / 2;

const FetchData = () => {
  const [data, setdata] = useState<DSVRowArray<string>>();

  const pieArc = arc().innerRadius(0).outerRadius(width);
  const colorPie = pie().value(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    csv(CSVURL).then(setdata); // Fetching data & updating data
  }, []);

  if (!data) {
    return <pre>loading...</pre>;
  }

  console.log(data[0]);

  return (
    <svg width={width} height={height}>
      <g transform={`translate(${centerX}, ${centerY})`}>
        {colorPie(data).map((d: PieArcDatum<number>) => (
          <path fill={d.data["RGB hex value"]} d={pieArc(d)} />
        ))}
      </g>
    </svg>
  );
};

export default FetchData;
```

The code executes but with error in **VSCode**. Errors of VSCode are in the picture.

[Errors of VSCode are in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBBxT.jpg)

I'm also pasting the errors here:

```
ERROR in src/components/FetchData/FetchData.tsx:99:19
TS2345: Argument of type 'DSVRowArray<string> | PieArcDatum<number>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(number | { valueOf(): number; })[]'.
  Type 'DSVRowArray<string>' is not assignable to type '(number | { valueOf(): number; })[]'.
    The types returned by 'pop()' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'DSVRowString<string> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number | { valueOf(): number; } | undefined'.
        Type 'DSVRowString<string>' is not assignable to type 'number | { valueOf(): number; } | undefined'.
          Type 'DSVRowString<string>' is not assignable to type '{ valueOf(): number; }'.
            The types returned by 'valueOf()' are incompatible between these types.
              Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'number'.
     97 |             } */}
     98 |
  >  99 |         {colorPie(data).map((d: DSVRowArray<string> | PieArcDatum<number>) => (
        |                   ^^^^
    100 |           <path
    101 |             key={Math.random()}
    102 |             fill={d.data["RGB hex value"]}

ERROR in src/components/FetchData/FetchData.tsx:99:29
TS2345: Argument of type '(d: DSVRowArray<string> | PieArcDatum<number>) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: PieArcDatum<number | { valueOf(): number; }>, index: number, array: PieArcDatum<number | { valueOf(): number; }>[]) => Element'.
  Types of parameters 'd' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'PieArcDatum<number | { valueOf(): number; }>' is not assignable to type 'DSVRowArray<string> | PieArcDatum<number>'.
      Type 'PieArcDatum<number | { valueOf(): number; }>' is not assignable to type 'PieArcDatum<number>'.
        Type 'number | { valueOf(): number; }' is not assignable to type 'number'.
          Type '{ valueOf(): number; }' is not assignable to type 'number'.
     97 |             } */}
     98 |
  >  99 |         {colorPie(data).map((d: DSVRowArray<string> | PieArcDatum<number>) => (
        |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  > 100 |           <path
        | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  > 101 |             key={Math.random()}
        | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  > 102 |             fill={d.data["RGB hex value"]}
        | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  > 103 |             d={pieArc(d)!}
        | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  > 104 |           />
        | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  > 105 |         ))}
        | ^^^^^^^^^^
    106 |       </g>
    107 |     </svg>
    108 |   );

ERROR in src/components/FetchData/FetchData.tsx:102:21
TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'DSVRowArray<string> | PieArcDatum<number>'.
  Property 'data' does not exist on type 'DSVRowArray<string>'.
    100 |           <path
    101 |             key={Math.random()}
  > 102 |             fill={d.data["RGB hex value"]}
        |                     ^^^^
    103 |             d={pieArc(d)!}
    104 |           />
    105 |         ))}

ERROR in src/components/FetchData/FetchData.tsx:103:23
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(this: any, d: DefaultArcObject, ...args: any[]): string | null', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'DSVRowArray<string> | PieArcDatum<number>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DefaultArcObject'.
      Type 'DSVRowArray<string>' is missing the following properties from type 'DefaultArcObject': innerRadius, outerRadius, startAngle, endAngle
  Overload 2 of 2, '(this: any, d: DefaultArcObject, ...args: any[]): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'DSVRowArray<string> | PieArcDatum<number>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DefaultArcObject'.
      Type 'DSVRowArray<string>' is not assignable to type 'DefaultArcObject'.
    101 |             key={Math.random()}
    102 |             fill={d.data["RGB hex value"]}
  > 103 |             d={pieArc(d)!}
        |                       ^
    104 |           />
    105 |         ))}
    106 |       </g>
```

In CodeSandBox it's working fine. No error. Playground : https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-cannon-bfxprg?file=/src/FetchData.tsx:0-975

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution -

```
import { arc, csv, DSVRowArray, pie, PieArcDatum } from "d3";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const CSVURL =
  "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mzs21/df0621d1ca5a25fa6baeeae93562c1a1/raw/CSSNamedColors.csv";

const width = 960;
const height = 500;
const centerX = width / 2;
const centerY = height / 2;


const FetchData = () => {
  const [data, setdata] = useState<DSVRowArray<string>>();

  const pieArc = arc().innerRadius(0).outerRadius(width);
  const colorPie = pie().value(1);


  useEffect(() => {
    csv(CSVURL).then(setdata); // Fetching data & updating data
  }, []);

  if (!data) {
    return <pre>loading...</pre>;
  }

  return (
    <svg width={width} height={height}>
      <g transform={`translate(${centerX}, ${centerY})`}>
        {colorPie(data as any).map(         // here
          (d: PieArcDatum<number | { valueOf(): number }>) => (
            <path
              key={Math.random()}
              fill={(d.data as { [key: string]: any })[ // here
                "RGB hex value"
              ].toString()}
              d={pieArc(d as any)!} // here
            />
          )
        )}
      </g>
    </svg>
  );
};

export default FetchData;
```

Any suggestion?

So, the data I'm fetching is not compatible with the data type of "pie" of D3. In this case, I'm using "any" data type to make it compatible.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: So, the data I'm fetching is not compatible with the data type of "pie" of D3. In this case, I'm using "any" data type to make it compatible.